# How to stop transfer of files to iCloud

Tags: icloud

I accidentally copied a very large folder on my desktop. I saw that iOS started copying my large folder to the iCloud

[image]

I googled and found that if I removed the folder it should stop copying. So I went to the terminal and did a "mv" command to move the folder back to its original location

But iCloud is still copying that folder and the dialog above cannot be dismissed because the "x" sign at the end of the status bar is greyed out. I cannot stop this copy operation in any way.....

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if anyone is still looking for an answer on how to stop transfer of files to iCloud, here's a workaround - you can just delete the destination folder on iCloud and it will immediately stop the operation. Had to do that when I was trying to copy 67 GB. Not sure what to do if there's no destination folder (ie destination is root).

Answer (score 1):

If you just can't wait for it to finish (I would just ignore and wait), you could disconnect from the network and then restart.

The iCloud sync respects the local filesystem, so any change there should be immediate once the network / restart changes.

You can log into iCloud.com as well once you clean things up / re-enable the network and give iCloud upload process a few tens of minutes to react and clean up.

I've had 10 GB go up one day, so as long as you aren't paying for the bandwidth and are close to an Apple data center (same half of a continent), 4 GB shouldn't take that long either to get uploaded and then delete.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I can see what is happening. even though the dialog can't be cancelled. The number of files is going down

[image]

So from 239K it has gone down to 126K. So I guess if I wait ... the number will drop to 0 and copy operation will stop.